# Subclassing scipy's continuous distributions

Tags: statistics, scipy

I'm trying to figure out how to create a new `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` subclass.  My distribution depends on "location" and "shape" parameters, but every example of a `_pdf` in `scipy.stats.distributions` assumes that the shape & location parameters can simply be applied to the X-axis, which is not the case for some distributions.

For example, one distribution I'm working with is a modified version of the lognormal in which the X-axis location explicitly depends on the width of the distribution, i.e.:

```
def _pdf(self, x, x0, s):
    Px = exp(-(log(x/x0)+s**2/2.)**2 / (2*s**2))
    return Px / (s*x0*sqrt(2*pi))
```

I'd like to be able to use `loc` for `x0` and `scale` for `s`.  Is there any way to do this, or is there a better way to subclass `rv_continuous`?

(note that simply using the PDF as I've defined it leads to problems in other `rv_continuous` methods, e.g. `.fit`, since `loc` and `scale` are still treated as "free parameters" even though they should not be)

Comment: You are missing a factor of `1/x0`.  Without it, the integral from 0 to infinty of the PDF is `x0`, not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't try to change the meaning of `loc` and `scale`.  They are the standard, well-defined location and scale parameters as explained, for example, in the [scipy.stats tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#shifting-and-scaling), on wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_parameter) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_parameter), and also [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda364.htm).

As I mentioned in a comment, it looks like you are missing a factor of `1/x0` in your formula.  Without it, the integral from 0 to infinity of your PDF is `x0`, not 1.

With the correction, it is clear that `x0` is actually the scale parameter.  `s` is a shape parameter.  Like many other distributions only defined on the positive real axis (e.g. gamma or log-normal), you can simply ignore the location parameter--its default value is 0. (If you use the `fit` method, be sure to use the argument `floc=0`, to prevent the method from treating `loc` as a free parameter.)  However, I'm not sure what you mean by "the X-axis location explicitly depends on the width of the distribution"--the X-axis location of *what*?

Comment: I suppose I'm working with distributions in a limited context, and I want to include the limitations.  I'm working with lognormal distributions where both the integral of the distribution and its first moment must be exactly 1, which imposes restrictions on the shape/scale parameters.  That said, I think the `floc=0` approach is probably what I need, and I should just make wrappers to hide `loc`

Comment: Accepting for `floc=0`, which I think is the part of the answer that addresses my question directly.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Warren's answer:

The distributions in scipy.stats assume that `loc` and `scale` are the usual standardization, `y = (x - loc) / scale`. So you cannot subclass the distributions if you don't follow that definition.

However, you can write a new wrapper class that delegates to a (sub)class of scipy.stats.distributions, and do any reparameterization in this wrapper class.

In that case you can fix some parameters like `loc` and change the names of parameters before calling the standard class.

Creating a lognorm wrapper with a more standard parameterization would make it easier to use when following for example a text book, but wouldn't do anything different from what can be done with the distribution in scipy.stats.

Comment: This makes great sense.  Would someone be able to point to some examples using this approach?

Comment: there is/was a `paramnormal` package and a newer one that I don't find anymore to reparameterize scipy distributions, e.g. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4538 and mentioned in other scipy issues that I also don't find anymore.An issue for creating new distributions https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/12133