# How to obtain a python scipy-type continuous rv distribution object that is bounded?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution

I would like to define a bounded version of a continuous random variable distribution (say, an exponential, but I might want to use others as well). The bounds are 0 and 1. I would like to

1. draw random variates (as done by `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.rvs`),
2. use the ppf (percentage point function) (as done by `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf`), and possibly
3. use the cdf (cumulative density function) (as done by `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.cdf`)

**Possible approaches I can think of:**

- Getting random variates in an ad hoc way is not difficult

  ```
  import scipy.stats
  d = scipy.stats.expon(0, 3/10.)    # an exponential distribution as an example 
  rv = d.rvs(size=target_number_of_rv)
  rv = rv[0=<rv]
  rv = rv[rv<=1]
  while len(rv) < target_number_of_rv:
      rv += d.rvs(1)
      rv = rv[0=<rv]
      rv = rv[rv<=1]
  ```

  but 1) this is non-generic and potentially error-prone and 2) it does not help with the ppf or cdf.
- Subclassing scipy.stats.rv_continuous, as [is done here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1659) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17093318/1735215). Thereby, the ppf of scipy.stats.rv_continuous can be used. The drawback is that it requires the pdf (not just a pre-defined rv_continuous object or the pdf of the unbounded distribution and the bounds), and if this is wrong, cdf and ppf and everything else will be wrong as well.
- Designing a class that cares for applying the bounds to the rv generation and for correcting the value of the ppf obtained from the unbounded object in scipy.stats. A drawback is that this is non-generic and error-prone as well and that it may be difficult to correct the ppf. My feeling is that the value of the cdf of the unbounded distribution could be scaled by what share of probability mass is out of the bounds (in total, lower and upper), but I may be wrong. That would be for lower and upper bounds l and u and any valid quantile x (with l<=x<=u): (cdf(x)-cdf(l))/(cdf(u)-cdf(l)). Obtaining the ppf would, however, require to invert the resulting function.

My feeling is that there might be a better and more generic way to do this. Is there? Maybe with sympy? Maybe by somehow obtaining the function object of the unbounded cdf and modifying it directly?

Python is version: 3.6.2, scipy is version 0.19.1.

Comment: A distribution which is bounded in the way you describe is conventionally called a "truncated" distribution. The properties of the truncated distribution are easily derived from the properties of the corresponding non-truncated distribution. One way to implement this is to have a class which represents a truncated distribution (of any kind). An instance of this class holds a reference to the corresponding non-truncated distribution, so you only have one truncated distribution class and apply it to any non-truncated distribution, as you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the distribution is one of those that is available in `scipy.stats` then you can evaluate its integral between the two bounds using the cdf for that distribution. Otherwise, you can define the pdf for `rv_continuous` and then use its cdf to get this integral.

Now, you have, in effect, the pdf for the bounded version of the pdf you want because you have calculated the normalising constant for it, in that integral. You can proceed to use `rv_continuous` with the form that you have for the pdf plus the normalising constant and with the bounds.

---

Here's what your code might be like. The variable `scale` is set according to the scipy documents. `norm` is the integral of the exponential pdf over [0,1]. Only about .49 of the probability mass is accounted for. Therefore, to make the exponential, when truncated to the [0,1] interval give a mass of one we must divide its pdf by this factor.

`Truncated_expon` is defined as a subclass of `rv_continuous` as in the documentation. By supplying its pdf we make it possible (at least for such a simple integral!) for scipy to calculate this distribution's cdf and thereby to calculate random samples.

I have calculated the cdf at one as a check.

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> lamda = 2/3
>>> scale = 1/lamda
>>> norm = stats.expon.cdf(1, scale=scale)
>>> norm
0.48658288096740798
>>> from math import exp
>>> class Truncated_expon(stats.rv_continuous):
...     def _pdf(self, x, lamda):
...         return lamda*exp(-lamda*x)/0.48658288096740798
... 
>>> e = Truncated_expon(a=0, b=1, shapes='lamda')
>>> e.cdf(1, lamda=lamda)
1.0
>>> e.rvs(size=20, lamda=lamda)
array([ 0.20064067,  0.67646465,  0.89118679,  0.86093035,  0.14334989,
        0.10505598,  0.53488779,  0.11606106,  0.41296616,  0.33650899,
        0.95126415,  0.57481087,  0.04495104,  0.00308469,  0.23585195,
        0.00653972,  0.59400395,  0.34919065,  0.91762547,  0.40098409])
```

Comment: Can I also use a frozen rv of the original, non-truncated distribution as an argument in the stats.rv_continuous subclass? This would generalize along the lines suggested by Robert Dodier in his comment to the OP. When I try to hand a frozen rv as an argument to `cdf()`, I get: `...  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 872, in _argcheck;    cond = logical_and(cond, (asarray(arg) > 0));TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'rv_frozen' and 'int'`

Comment: Please post this as a new question. I'm willing to look at it if you let me know about it with a comment here.